# How can I implement a vmappable sum over a dynamic range in Jax?

Tags: python, numpy, jax, automatic-differentiation, autodiff

I want to implement something like the following Python function in Jax, and wrap it with a call to `vmap`. I want it to be fully **reverse-mode** differentiable (with respect to `x`) using `grad()`, even after the vmap.

```
def f(x,kmax):
  return sum ([x**k for k in range(1,kmax+1)])
```

(This is a deliberately simplified version of the function; I realize in this case I could use the closed-form expression for the geometric series; sadly the actual function I'm trying to implement does not have a closed-form sum that I'm aware of.)

Is there any way to do this? It seems like there *has* to be; but `fori_loop` is not reverse-mode differentiable if `kmax` is dynamic, `jax.lax.scan` needs a statically-shaped array or it will throw `ConcretizationTypeError`s, and similarly Python primitives like `range` (as used above) throw `TracerIntegerConversionError` if wrapped in `vmap`.

I think I understand the restrictions on needing arrays to be fixed-shape, but every autodiff framework I've ever used allows you to construct arbitrarily-sized expressions dynamically *somehow*. A sum over a varying integer range is a pretty basic mathematical tool. How does one implement this in Jax?

EDITED to refocus the problem definition (the issue is more vmap than grad) and provide the following examples.

This, specifically, is what I'd like to be able to do

```
import jax

def f(x,kmax):
  return sum ([x**k for k in range(1,kmax+1)])

fmap = jax.vmap(f,in_axes=(None,-1))

x = 3.
kmaxes = jax.numpy.array([1,2,3])

print(fmap(x,kmaxes))

fmap_sum = lambda k,kmaxes:jax.numpy.sum(fmap(k,kmaxes))

print(fmap_sum(x,kmaxes))
print(jax.grad(fmap_sum)(x,kmaxes))
```

This throws a TracerIntegerConversionError at `range(1,kmax+1)`.
What I would like it to be doing is something like this:

```
import jax

def f(x,kmax):
  return sum ([x**k for k in range(1,kmax+1)])

def fmap(x,kmaxes):
  return [f(x,kmax) for kmax in kmaxes]

x = 3.
kmaxes = jax.numpy.array([1,2,3])

print(fmap(x,kmaxes))

def fmap_sum(x,kmaxes):
  return sum(fmap(x,kmaxes))

print(fmap_sum(x,kmaxes))
print(jax.grad(fmap_sum)(x,kmaxes))
```

which gives the correct result (but loses the parallelization and acceleration of vmap).

Comment: Reverse-mode differentiation of your `f` function with respect to `x` works as written (try `jax.jacrev(f, argnums=0)(1.0, 5)`) Can you edit your question to add a more complete example that demonstrates the issue you're having?

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp. Your question made me realize the primary issue I'm facing is more to do with vmap than grad. I've edited the question to reflect this. Any thoughts you might have would be appreciated - Ian

Comment: (Incidentally, now I understand that grad works through Python's regular sum(), this is no longer such a blocking issue for me, but I would still like to be able to vmap it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make your function compatible with `vmap`, you'll need to replace the Python control flow with [`jax.lax` control flow](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#control-flow) operations. In this case, `lax.fori_loop` seems applicable:

```py
def f1(x, k):
  def body_fun(i, val):
    return val + x ** i
  return jax.lax.fori_loop(1, k + 1, body_fun, jnp.zeros_like(x))

f1map = jax.vmap(f1, (None, 0))
print(f1map(x, kmaxes))
# [ 3. 12. 39.]
```

But because the size of the loop is dynamic, this is not compatible with reverse-mode autodiff:

```py
jax.jacrev(f1map)(x, kmaxes)
# ValueError: Reverse-mode differentiation does not work for lax.while_loop or lax.fori_loop. Try using lax.scan instead.
```

To get around this, you can modify your function such that it uses a static loop size. Here's one way you might do that:

```py
def f2(x, k, kmax):  # kmax should be static
  def body_fun(i, val):
    return val + jnp.where(i <= k, x ** i, 0)
  return jax.lax.fori_loop(1, kmax + 1, body_fun, jnp.zeros_like(x))

f2map = jax.vmap(f2, (None, 0, None))

print(f2map(x, kmaxes, kmaxes.max()))  # compatible with vmap
# [ 3. 12. 39.]

print(jax.jacrev(f2map)(x, kmaxes, kmaxes.max()))  # and with reverse-mode autodiff
# [ 1.  7. 34.]
```