# Vectorizing power of `jax.grad`

Tags: python, loops, vectorization, jax

I'm trying to vectorize the following "power-of-grad" function so that it accepts multiple `order`s: ([see here](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/18834))

```
def grad_pow(f, order, argnum):

    for i in jnp.arange(order):
        f = grad(f, argnums=argnum)

    return f
```

This function produces the following error after applying `vmap` on the argument `order`:

```
jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: traced array with shape int32[].
It arose in the jnp.arange argument 'stop'
```

I have tried writing a static version of `grad_pow` using `jax.lax.cond` and `jax.lax.scan`, following the logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76334231/how-can-i-implement-a-vmappable-sum-over-a-dynamic-range-in-jax):

```
def static_grad_pow(f, order, argnum):

    order_max = 3  ## maximum order

    def grad_pow(f, i):
        return cond(i <= order, grad(f, argnum), f), None

    return scan(grad_pow, f, jnp.arange(order_max+1))[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_func = lambda x: jnp.exp(-2*x)
    test_func_grad_pow = static_grad_pow(jax.tree_util.Partial(test_func), 1, 0)
    print(test_func_grad_pow(1.))
```

Nevertheless, this solution still produces an error:

```
    return cond(i <= order, grad(f, argnum), f), None
TypeError: differentiating with respect to argnums=0 requires at least 1 positional arguments to be passed by the caller, but got only 0 positional arguments.
```

Just wondering how this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue with your question is that a vmapped function cannot return a function, it can only return arrays. All other details aside, that precludes any possibility of writing a valid function that does what you intend.

There are alternatives: for example, rather than attempting to create a function that will return a function, you could instead create a function that accepts arguments and applies that function to those arguments.

In that case, you'll run into another issue: if `n` is traced, there is no way to apply `grad` `n` times. JAX transformations like `grad` are evaluated at trace-time, and traced values like `n` are not available until runtime. One way to work around this is to pre-define all the functions you're interested in, and to use `lax.switch` to choose between them at runtime. The result would look something like this:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=[0], static_argnames=['argnum', 'max_order'])
def apply_multi_grad(f, order, *args, argnum=0, max_order=10):
  funcs = [f]
  for i in range(max_order):
    funcs.append(jax.grad(funcs[-1], argnum))
  return jax.lax.switch(order, funcs, *args)


order = jnp.arange(3)
x = jnp.ones(3)
f = jnp.sin

print(jax.vmap(apply_multi_grad, in_axes=(None, 0, 0))(f, order, x))
# [ 0.84147096  0.5403023  -0.84147096]

# Compare by doing it manually:
print(jnp.array([f(x[0]), jax.grad(f)(x[1]), jax.grad(jax.grad(f))(x[2])]))
# [ 0.84147096  0.5403023  -0.84147096]
```